# Best way to ban words

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I wan't create word-ban system into technical support script.

But I can't imagine how to design json and foreach in them.

Plan:

```
  "banned_words": [
    {
        word, word2, word3, word4
        message: why we banned this words
    }
    {
        help, mail, register, email
        message: we know whats the problem, be patient
    }
  ]
```

How JSON design should be and how can I foreach in them?

I'm checking ticket messages with **strpos()** function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there isn't valid JSON. (I assume you already knew that.) To turn what you have into valid JSON, you'll need to change a couple of things.

- Quote all your keys and string values with `"`.
- For your list of words in each object in `banned_words`, you'll need
  to enclose them in an array `[]` and assign them a key.

You should end up with JSON like this:

```
{"banned_words": [
    {
        "words": ["word", "word2", "word3", "word4"],
        "message": "why we banned this words"
    },
    {
        "words": ["help", "mail", "register", "email"],
        "message": "we know whats the problem, be patient"
    }
  ]
}
```

After you have the JSON, you can loop over the lists of words and their corresponding messages like this:

```
$word_lists = json_decode($json);

foreach ($word_lists->banned_words as $set) {
    $message = $set->message;
    foreach ($set->words as $word) {
        // do something with the word
    }
}
```

(How to actually implement the word ban system from this point is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.)